# Neo4j: spring-data-neo4j,how to cast result to my type class?

Tags: casting, neo4j, grails-domain-class, spring-data-neo4j

I have insert some node into Neo4j DB.And I want to select some node from database and cast it to specific class.

Here are some code about the problem:

```
class Service {
    Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate

    @Transactional
    def find() {
        def id1 = 11
        //Knowledge k = neo4jTemplate.findOne(1, Knowledge)
        Result result = neo4jTemplate.query("start n=node(11) return ID(n),n.name,n.age;", null)
    //how to cast the result to User class
        println "the tpye of result called User is  "+   result.to(User.class).is(cn.edu.bnuz.itc.bok.sub2.User.class)
    }

}
```

The detail about node like :

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[11]{career:"programmer",name:"kelvin",age:35,introduce:"lazy doy"} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

        @NodeEntity
        class User {
        @GraphId
        Long id;
        String name;
        int age;
}
```

I just want get the node's id, name, age from db and put it into a User class.
But it failed many time with many method.

Here I have encounter a problem which is :How can I cast the result to my target class? I have try many method to cast but fail finally.Thank you for you attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the user node from the query and call the `to` method of the returned `Result` with the desired class as argument:

```
Result result = neo4jTemplate.query("start n=node(11) return n", null);
for(User u : result.to(User.class)) {
    doSomethingWith(u);
}
```

You may want to consider [using repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference%3aprogramming-model%3arepositories) that [support cypher queries](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#d5e1145) like:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    @Query("start n=node(11) return n")
    Iterable<User> getUser11();
}
```

Comment: Ok,It works now.
Thank you so much.
I have tried following method to achieve it.


Result result = neo4jTemplate.query("start n=node(11) return ID(n),n.name,n.age;", null)
List<User> list = result.collect{new User(it)}

Two method can fulfill my requirement.
At the end, thanks again.

Comment: you can also use: `result.to(User.class).as(List.class)`